# Xcode4 derived/build/intermediate products data path: must it really be defined in user settings?

Tags: xcode, build, product, derived

Plenty resources tell how to set these folders, but I am still not satisfied with the infrastructure. What I need is this:

- I do not want to use Default folders (as preset in clean Xcode 4 installation, with default Project or Workspace settings).
- I want to put them into a dir relative to Project (or Workspace)

Hence I made necessary changes to Project settings, files are being put where expected, but Project as well as Workspace setting, that tells Xcode to put the eproducts where they shell be, are stored in xcuserdata/$USER.xcuserdatad/Workspace{or Project}.settings.

Which (.settings) is naturally unacceptable to be tracked in SCM.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_BuildLocationStyle</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_BuildSubfolderNameStyle</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_DerivedDataCustomLocation</key>
    <string>obj/iphone</string>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_DerivedDataLocationStyle</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_IssueFilterStyle</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_LiveSourceIssuesEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_SnapshotAutomaticallyBeforeSignificantChanges</key>
    <true/>
    <key>IDEWorkspaceUserSettings_SnapshotLocationStyle</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

As a result - if there is another checkout made by other user, he opens the Project (or Workspace), ending up with build products being put into default paths (user's home folder), instead of those specified in Workspace{or Project}.settings XML file - because, the xcuserdata/ folder is not tracked and user has different login of course.

I would expect the XML file sibling the contents.xcworspace XML, wiht possibliity to override in user-settings. Obivously, this is not available, at least not documented, is it?

So is there another possibility that would fit my needs?

Comment: Note: setting the SYMROOT and OBJROOT variables on project or target build setting level has confusing effect - only Logs, .hmap files and something called Index/ is put where desired, while  intermediates and products are put in user's Home folder.